# Hive external tables map to azure blob storage

Tags: apache-spark, hive, azure-storage, hana

Is there a way to create a Hive external table using  with location pointing to Azure Storage? We actually want to connect `SAP HANA (SDA)` to blob storage, so it seems the only way is to  create an external hive table first which points to Azure blob storage and then use Hive ODBC connector/spark connector`to connect  it to`HANA SAP`. Does anyone have any idea how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create external tables in Hive or Spark on Azure. There are several options available:

- Azure HDInsight
- Azure Databricks (via Spark)
- Hadoop distros supporting Azure Blob Storage (e. g. [HDP](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.1/bk_cloud-data-access/content/wasb-get-started.html))

External table creation would reference the data in the Blob storage account. See the following example for a Hive table created in HDInsight (wasb is used in the location):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <database name>.<external textfile table name>
    (
        field1 string,
        field2 int,
        ...
        fieldN date
    )
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '<field separator>'
        lines terminated by '<line separator>' STORED AS TEXTFILE
        LOCATION 'wasb:///<directory in Azure blob>' 
TBLPROPERTIES("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

or in Azure Databricks:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (name STRING, age INT)
   COMMENT 'This table is created with existing data'
   LOCATION 'wasbs://<storage-account@<containername>.blob.core.windows.net/<directory>'
```

See also:

- [HDInsight Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/team-data-science-process/move-hive-tables)
- [Azure Databricks Documentation](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-table.html#create-table)

I don' t know what SAP supports. ODBC-Access is possible to all of the solutions.